# hyper-v on personal laptop slow internet in vm

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I started ubuntu 18.04 VM using hyper-v.
I am using a laptop with wifi.
I am using an external switch in order to connect to wifi inside the VM.

My internet speed in the windows is 100mbps but when I download something inside the VM I can download at most 10kb/s.

I tried to find a solution all over the internet but didn't find anything.

What can I do? If more information is needed so just ask.

Comment: Did you check if Windows or Ubuntu downloading any stuff in background? Does VM have sufficient CPU cores and memory?

Comment: Are you using the Default switch? Tries: (1) Update NIC driver, (2) In the host NIC properties of IPv4 disable Large Send Offload, (3) disable the antivirus.

Comment: @Biswapriyo nothing in the background, I put 4 cores and 10GB ram.

Comment: @harrymc already did all of this and tried external and default switch.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create an external switch at all, you simply need to add the [Default switch](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/what-s-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update/ba-p/382399) to the Ubuntu VM's settings and remove the external switch.  The default switch will use whatever internet connection the laptop is using; per Microsoft _"The Default Switch offers the best networking experience for virtual machines on a laptop.  If you need highly customized networking, however, continue using Virtual Switch Manager."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The solution in my case was to disable the large send offload for IPv4.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the [Default switch](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/what-s-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update/ba-p/382399)?  Per Microsoft: _"The Default Switch offers the best networking experience for virtual machines on a laptop.  If you need highly customized networking, however, continue using Virtual Switch Manager."_

Comment: Cent OS 7 here and this seems to have helped too.

Comment: @JW0914 If your use requires these VMs to be accessible on the intranet, Default Switch won't be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- Use the Ubuntu VM from the Microsoft gallery using
  [Hyper-V Quick Create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/quick-create-virtual-machine).
  This VM is most probably already created with the right drivers for Hyper-V.
- Install the Ubuntu kernel `linux-azure` as explained in the article
  [Supported Ubuntu virtual machines on Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the "Large Send Offload Version 2" as the other answer suggested, what worked for my Wi-Fi card was disabling the "**Packet Coalescing**" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately worked for me:

```
sudo apt install ethtool
sudo ethtool -K eth0 tso off
```

You can check whether it worked by running:

```
sudo ethtool -k eth0 | grep 'tcp-segmentation-offload'
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python
```

I now get the full upload speed of my ISP, which is 40:

[image: Upload speeds]